# Use value in dictionary in a functional select

Tags: kdb

I have the following dictionary: `` d:(enlist `p)!enlist `sym ``

I want to run the following query in functional select form, replacing  `` `sym `` with `` d`p ``

`` select from tbl where sym in `a`b`c ``

`` ?[tbl;enlist(in;`sym;enlist `a`b`c);0b;()] ``

So far I've tried to replace `` `sym `` with  `` (@;`d;enlist`p) ``, but that doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Would `` d`p `` not work?

```
q)d:`p`p2!`sym`sym2
q)tbl:([]sym:`a`z;sym2:`z`b)
q)
q)?[tbl;enlist(in;d`p;enlist`a`b`c);0b;()]
sym sym2
--------
a   z
q)?[tbl;enlist(in;d`p2;enlist`a`b`c);0b;()]
sym sym2
--------
z   b
```

Comment: I am trying to do it if d was a symbol because in the scenario where the name of the dict is stored in a variable, I would have to use `d.

Comment: Terry's answer still works if `d` is a variable,  ``c:`d``  ``?[tbl;enlist(in;c`p;enlist`a`b`c);0b;()]``

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a symbol variable name for the dictionary, then this should work:

```
?[`tbl;enlist (in; @[`d;`p]; enlist `a`b`c);0b;()]
```

i.e.

```
{?[`tbl;enlist (in; @[x;`p]; enlist `a`b`c);0b;()]}[`d]
```